# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using `AlertDialog` in my program, whenever i do tap on any of the item in Dialog, always getting:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
```

Here is my implementation :

```
      builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

          Log.d("which::--", String.valueOf(which));

       });
```

Comment: post full source code

Comment: @sasikumar but why you need full source code ?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException so you did mistake in array ..thats why need code for reference

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution to get `index or position` of tapped item:

```
int selectedPosition = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the "which" parameter indicates "The button that was clicked (e.g. BUTTON1) or the position of the item clicked."

Here you put your listener (DialogInterface.OnClickListener()) on your PositiveButton so "which" will always return BUTTON1 or BUTTON_POSITIVE (see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html).

You must put your listener on your list using the function

`setSingleChoiceItems (CharSequence[] items, int checkedItem, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)` for example or `setMultiChoiceItems (CharSequence[] items, boolean[] checkedItems, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)` if you want to allow multi-items selection.